# Arrow function that expects 2 numbers and returns undefined if they aren't numbers

Tags: javascript, function

Need help. Need an arrow function that expects 2 numbers as input (e.g. 1, 2)
and returns the sum of the two numbers. If anything other than 2 numbers is passed, return undefined.
Not sure where I'm going wrong on this.

```
const sum = (num1, num2) => {
    
if((num1.value !== 0)||(num2.value !== 0)){
    return undefined
}
    return num1 + num2
}
console.log(sum(4,4))
```

Just keeps returning undefined, and doesn't go to finding sum.

Comment: Why would a number have a value property? Not sure where you learned that.  And your code says if a `X is not equal to zero than return undefined`.

Comment: Why do you have .value?

Comment: Ive changed it quite a few times.. My frustration was getting high.. and desperation set in to solve this. .value was just theory crafting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

```js
const sum = (num1, num2) => {
  if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return num1 + num2;
};
console.log(sum(4, 4));
```

Comment: After reading what isNan was... seems way simpler to use then what I was being asked to make :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a submember of a number value, not an object, so you will always get something you don't want to get.
This should work better :

```
const sum = (num1, num2) => {
if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)){
    return undefined
}
    return num1 + num2
}
console.log(sum(4,4))
```

You should also look what is isNaN which is a better way to check if you do receive a number or not :)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Answer (score 0):

I think what are are looking for is something like this.

```
const sum = (num1, num2) => {
    if (typeof(num1) !== "number" || typeof(num2) !== "number")
        return "undefined";

    return num1 + num2;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! this worked! Closer to how I orignally had it.. so instead of "number" I had a straight 0 value... Ty all!